# Bootstrap code not working on server

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to build bootstrap validation form to validate each field and flash error if any.I included bootstrap validation js and css using link.
This is my code

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Boostrap Validator</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <br/>
       <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Content</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #messages is where the messages are placed inside -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <div id="messages"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    </body>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
        container: '#messages',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            fullName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The email address is not valid'
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The title is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 100,
                        message: 'The title must be less than 100 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            content: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The content is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 500,
                        message: 'The content must be less than 500 characters long'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</html>
```

Everything working properly on browser on localhost but show error on server.When i host on server then this bootstrap code are not executing.
I don't understand why this kind of error are occurs.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error on console ??

Answer (score 1):

This way seems to be working fine

```
 <html lang="en">
    <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Boostrap Validator</title>


  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>

</head>
    <body>
        <br/>
       <form id="contactForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Full name</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullName" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Email</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Title</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Content</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #messages is where the messages are placed inside -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <div id="messages"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Validate</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.0/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactForm').bootstrapValidator({
        container: '#messages',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            fullName: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            email: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    emailAddress: {
                        message: 'The email address is not valid'
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The title is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 100,
                        message: 'The title must be less than 100 characters long'
                    }
                }
            },
            content: {
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The content is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        max: 500,
                        message: 'The content must be less than 500 characters long'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
    </script>
</html>
```